# Paying Employees

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm

Say for example I want to give some money to some employees.Each employee MUST get between $a and $b dollars. The first employee gets $a and each subsequent employee gets $k more than the last until that amount would exceed $b, in which case that employee gets $b and each subsequent employee thereafter gets $k Less than the last until that amount falls below $a in which case the employee would get $a and the cycle continues for all n employees. I want to return the total payout to all employees

What I have so far:

```
#!/bin/python3
import os
import sys

def payEmp(n, a, b, k):
    totalPayOut = 0
    currentPay = 0
    increase = True
    for i in range(n):
        if increase == True:
            if currentPay < a:
                currentPay += a
            else:
                currentPay += k
                if currentPay >= b:
                    totalPayOut += b
                    increase = False
                else:
                    totalPayOut += currentPay
        else:
            currentPay -= k
            if currentPay <= a:
                totalPayOut += a
                increase = True
            else:
                totalPayOut += currentPay

    return totalPayOut



if __name__ == '__main__':
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')

    t = int(input())

    for t_itr in range(t):
        nabk = input().split()

        n = int(nabk[0])

        a = int(nabk[1])

        b = int(nabk[2])

        k = int(nabk[3])

        result = payEmp(n, a, b, k)

        fptr.write(str(result) + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

Comment: You should describe an actual problem. Also, check this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) how to ask question properly.

Comment: I edited your description - links are only welcome if they are "adorners" - the problem as stated should be understandable w/o the link  - only by reading your question.

Comment: This has a cute answer using infinite lists in Haskell. `f n a b k = sum . take n . concat . cycle $ [[a, a+k..b], [b, b-k..a]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the Haskell solution I posted as a comment on the question, here is a solution using the `itertools` library that uses an infinite list of values.

```
import itertools

def pay(n, a, b, k):
    cyc = itertools.cycle([range(a, b+1, k), range(b, a-1, -k)])
    chained = itertools.chain.from_iterable(cyc)
    return sum(itertools.islice(chained, n))
```

This works because the pattern we're encapsulating with this algorithm is the infinitely cyclic pattern `[range(a, b+1, k), range(b, a-1, -k)]` (walk by `k` from `a` to `b`, then walk by `-k` from `b` to `a`). `itertools.chain.from_iterable` draws from the individual `range` iterators, and `islice` makes sure we only take `n` of the results.

`cyc` and `chained` are infinite series, and `islice` is doing the job of limiting to `n` students.

Comment: The itertools example works and I understand it after conducting some research. Thank you! But it is kinda slow though

Comment: @TheMan I'm not sure it's appreciably slower than any other method of doing this in Python, is it?

Comment: It is faster than mine

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use a generator function to create the payouts:

```
def pay(n,a,b,k):
    p = a # start with a
    c = 0
    while c < n: # loop until enough values generated
        # upcounting payments
        while p <= b and c < n:  # do this until enough or payment reached b
            yield p
            c += 1
            if p != b:
                p = min(b,p+k) # increase as long as not reached, prevent overshooting      
            else: # we reached and yielded b so we are done
                break # we just yielded b - less payment from now on
        p -= k  # we already yielded b - so we add k again
        # downcounting payments
        while p >= a and c < n:  # do this until enough or payment reached a again
            yield p
            c += 1
            if p != a:
                p = max(a,p-k) # decrease as long as not reached, prevent undershooting
            else: # we just yielded a, were done going down, back up from now on
                p = a+k
                break # we just printed a, more pay from here on

pays = list(pay(15,2,9,2))
print(pays,sum(pays))
```

Output:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 4, 6, 8, 9, 7, 5] 85
```

Comment: This gives me an incorrect result for n,a,b,k = 7 1 3 1

Comment: @TheMan result is `[1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3] 14` -why is that wrong? Its 7 results and you undulate between 1 and 3 and back , inc/dec by 1...

Comment: This gives me an incorrect result for n,a,b,k = 7 1 3 1.
I should get 13 but I get 14. Why?

Comment: Notice that person 4 would have been scheduled to receive 4 because of the increase by 1 (because k = 1 ) for each person, but because that exceeds b = 3 , person 4 receives exactly b = 3  instead. Similarly person 7 receives 1 instead of 0, and if there were a person 8, he would have received 2.

So we have 1 + 2 + 3 + 3 + 2 + 1 + 1
The total number given out is 13.

Comment: @TheMan Remove the `p -= k` after the first break and `p = a+k` before the second break. I read your description so that you only ever give out one b (and a) - not double up on a and b